# Creating a logging system using Swift

Tags: ios, macos, swift, logging

I'm trying to make a logging system that reads from a "log.txt" file and displays it to a NSTextView in my ViewController. Here's what I have,

```
while(server.listen()) {
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(1)
    self.consoleOutput.string! = log.read()
}
```

log.read() outputs a "log.txt" file.

self.consoleOutput.string! updates the NSTextView

It freezes up immediately, any ideas on how to approach this? It's my first time creating a log system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(x)` freezes your app, so that's not what you are looking for. You want to execute code every second, so one way of doing this would be using the NSTimer-class. Here is some example you can use:

```
var timer: NSTimer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "timerFired:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timer?.fire()
    }

func timerFired(timer: NSTimer) {
        self.consoleOutput.string! = log.read()
    }
```

To stop the timer you call `timer?.invalidate()`.